# How do you use the Pixastic fastblur to blur all the images on a page onLoad?

Tags: javascript, image, blur, pixastic

On http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/blurfast/ , their tutorial shows how to blur a single image.

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    Pixastic.process(img, "blurfast", {amount:0.5});
 } document.body.appendChild(img);
 img.src = "myimage.jpg";
```

How would I go about blurring all the images on a page and then making a button to revert them back to their original unblurred state?

Thanks in advance!